# Whenever create project and deploy application it goes on asia region bucket

Tags: google-app-engine

I remove the bucket manually but whever deploy it create automatically bucket in asia region, I want to change te region location because i am getting error [8]  quota.

i have modify location but again its creating auto bucket in asia region

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region

Can you please advice...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set up the location of your App Engine app it can not be changed.

You can see this information in [this official documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) regarding the App Engine location.

Also it is stated about the default App Engine bucket:

> When you create an app, App Engine creates a default bucket in Cloud Storage. Generally, the location of this bucket is the region matching the location of your App Engine app.